# check one item of an array against all others individually

Tags: javascript

Given the following array:

```
const arr = [11, 44, 88]
```

How can I check one number against another in the array individually? e.g.

```
check --> 11 against 44 | 11 against 88;
check --> 44 against 11 | 44 against 88;
check --> 88 against 11 | 88 against 44;
```

I was able to do this with nested loops, which does the job, but I was wondering if there's a better solution?

It should also be noted that some comparisons are redundant, such as 11 against 44 and 44 against 11.

Comment: For certain types of checks (for example, checking for duplicates), better algorithms are available, but the general case is `O(n ^ 2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible to improve on the computational complexity of two loops, `O(n ^ 2)`, but you can reduce redundant checks by starting the second loop at the index past the outer index:

```js
const arr = [11, 44, 88];

arr.forEach((num1, i) => {
  for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
    console.log(num1, 'vs', arr[j]);
  }
});
```